# regex to find the longest of matches

Tags: php, regex

I have the following regex:

```
(\b[1-9]+[.,][0-9]+[.,]?[0-9]+)#u
```

trying to match and extract the string 185,000 in:

```
ABBY TOP Colour : POLKA BLACK Weight : 0,18 Price : 185,000 Material : Kaos Semi-Fleece Size : Panjang / Length: 55 cm (depan), 72 (belakang)
```

and the string 20000 in:

```
"Jualan @20.000 "
```

however this doesn't match the 20.000, it just matches null. I also wanted it to match 3 digit in the middle and last part of the digits, so I change it to:

```
(\b[1-9]+[.,][0-9]{3}[.,]?[0-9]{3})#u
```

this is to prevent the regex to match:

```
20,00
```

and only match `20,000` or `20,000,000` or `20.000.000`

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about just:

```
\d+(?:[,.]\d{3})+
```

A nice simple regex.

Answer (score 1):

Correct regex should be:

```
(?<![.,])\b([1-9]\d*(?:[.,]\d{3})*)\b(?![.,])
```

i.e. digit `1-9` followed by 0 or more digits before period or comma.

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vP6xJ6/3)

Comment: how do I enforce the thousands? for example we're still matching this now 200.00 and this 200.000.00 , however the two is invalid

Comment: Pls clarify. Do you mean to validate that comma must always followed by 3 digits?

Comment: yes, a comma or a dot should always be followed by 3 digits

Comment: that is the standard formatting of a price, because 2.00 is invalid in my currency, nor 2.000.00 or 2,000,00

Comment: But `1234` should be a good match? Then even `55` or `72` should also match above isn't it?

Comment: yes that is correct, 1234 should be a good match or 55 or 72 too

Comment: is it possible to give another option where the string needs to have a . or , . So 1234 is invalid, 55 is invalid, 721 is also invalid.

Comment: It is confusing now since above you wrote `55` and `72` are valid. Please don't change nature of the problem completely.

Comment: Do you have any question/clarification on this problem?